# Latex to PDF publishing with and without comments

Tags: latex, tex, pdflatex, xelatex

I created a file using TeXstudio, I have lots of comments in the document. I want publish the document one version with the comments and the other without it. Is three a way to put on and off comments when publishing a PDF file in LaTEX?

Comment: What do you mean as 'comment'? Lines introduced `%` or margin notes e.g. `\todo[color=red]{comment}` ?

Comment: @arkhy Hi! Cross-network duplicates are not to be encouraged. What I suggest is to flag a question for migration, if you believe, and to post _next_ questions on tex.SE, where a more specialized audience would answer

Answer (score 1):

I think, you mean the comments by you as todo notes. If so, you can do use

```
%\usepackage[]{todonotes}
 \usepackage[disable]{todonotes}
```

to disable comments and use

```
\usepackage[]{todonotes}
%\usepackage[disable]{todonotes}
```

to get the comments in the pdf.

Alternatively, you can use if statements around the comments. But personally, I prefer the former.